# How to Read CSV file and count records from specific column

Tags: java, spring-boot, csv

I have one csv file which contains 4 fields(columns). Out of 4 columns I want to read second and want to read specific column First_name of csv file and count records using column  using Java.Please help.

```
ID First_name Last_name Gender
1   abc       robert     F
2   abc       foord      M
3   pqr       robert     F
4   cde       foord      F

I want output as below:
{
  "First_name":[
     {
        "abc":"2"
     },
     {
        "pqr":"1"
     },
     {
        "cde":"1"
     }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Check Jackson CSV library.  https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text/tree/master/csv

Answer (score 0):

You could use https://github.com/simoc/csvjdbc with this query:

```
SELECT First_name, COUNT(*) FROM sample GROUP BY First_name
```

Output to stdout:

```
First_name;COUNT(*)
abc;2
pqr;1
cde;1
```

This is of course not a full answer, but is a good tool to start of the process of coding this